# SQL UNION ALL with Unique Grouping in each block

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, union

I have an auto-dealers classifieds site. For the sake of understanding 'how' to do this, I've left out details on my table structure to make this example simple.

Dealers are either Bronze, Silver, Gold, Platinum
Dealers sell Cars, Trucks, Vans, SUVs

Lets say Cars, Trucks, Vans, and SUVs are in their own table. So we have the following Tables:

```
  1. Dealers (DealerID, DealerName, DealerLevel <-- 1 for Bronze, 2 for Silver, etc.)
  2. Cars (CarID, DealerID, CarName)
  3. Trucks (TruckID, DealerID, TruckName
  4. Vans (VanID, DealerID, VanName)
  5. SUVs (SUVID, DealerID, SUVName)
```

Lets say we have this:

```
SELECT DealerID, DealerName AS Title FROM Dealers
UNION ALL
SELECT CarID, CarName AS Title FROM Cars
UNION ALL
SELECT TruckID, TruckName AS Title FROM Trucks
UNION ALL
SELECT VanID, VanName AS Title FROM Vans
UNION ALL
SELECT SUVID, SUVName AS Title FROM SUVs
```

I need the results to be in the following order in each block. I say block to separate the different unions, but I understand it's a single result set in the end.

**First block:**
List all Dealers in order of Platinum first, then gold, silver, and bronze.
Randomly sort Platinum, Gold, Silver and bronze within themselves ( so no one complains about someone always showing up above them )

**Second block:**
List all Cars with the same method as mentioned previously.

Third, Fourth, and so on.

You might be wondering, why? I'm generating a full JSON output for the results which marked by their category and parsed in a jQuery auto suggest/complete plugin. Think of Facebook when you see the different headings and sections.

Thank you for any advice and/or examples!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a constant to each SELECT, and use that to define your blocks. Then sort by that constant, as well as any other value you might want to sort your data by (DealerLevel, as in your example). To sort randomly, add a NEWID() column:

```
SELECT DealerID, DealerName
FROM
(
    SELECT 1 AS MyConst, DealerLevel, DealerID, DealerName AS Title 
      FROM Dealers
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, DealerLevel, CarID, CarName 
      FROM Cars INNER JOIN Dealers ON Dealers.DealerId = Cars.DealerId
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, DealerLevel, TruckID, TruckName 
      FROM Trucks INNER JOIN Dealers ON Dealers.DealerId = Trucks.DealerId
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, DealerLevel, VanID, VanName 
      FROM Vans INNER JOIN Dealers ON Dealers.DealerId = Vans.DealerId
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 5, DealerLevel, SUVID, SUVName 
      FROM SUVs INNER JOIN Dealers ON Dealers.DealerId = SUVs.DealerId
) T
ORDER BY MyConst, DealerLevel DESC, NEWID() ;
```

Comment: Edited my post to address the "random" requirement and the sorting by DealerLevel in the subsequent blocks.

Comment: Nice, simplified it a bit.

Comment: @user1447679 you could also keep the `MyConst` in the external SELECT level, so your applications can identify where the blocks start and end.